# ActiveStorage - Select Images to Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a form where the user can see the images uploaded and also can remove one at a time. But what I want is to have checkboxes next to each image so the user can select the images he wants to remove and then press a button to remove them.

Right now this is what I have:

## _form.html.erb

```
<% if @vehicle.images.attached? %>
  <% @vehicle.images.each do |img| %>
    <div class="box_image">
      <div class="box_content">
        <%= image_tag img %>
        <div class="overlay">
          <%= link_to delete_upload_vehicle_url(@vehicle, img.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm_swal: 'Tem a certeza que quer eliminar esta imagem?' }, class:"delete_image" do %>
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

## vehicles_controller.rb

```
def delete_upload
  attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:upload_id])
  attachment.purge
  redirect_back(fallback_location: vehicles_path)
end
```

## routes.rb

```
resources :vehicles do
  member do
    delete "delete_upload/:upload_id", action: :delete_upload, as: :delete_upload
  end
end
```

## Image

[image]

How can I accomplish what I want? If someone could give me an example I would appreciate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you need to define a check  box  for each  image  which can be selected with a form which  will be submitted on click of a button

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_images_path, method: :delete do %>
<% if @vehicle.images.attached? %>
  <% @vehicle.images.each do |img| %>
    <div class="box_image">
      <div class="box_content">
        <%= image_tag img %>
        <%= check_box_tag "deleted_img_ids[]", img.id %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<% end %>
```

in your controller you can do following :

vehicles_controller.rb:

```
def destroy_multiple
  attachments = ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(id: params[:deleted_img_ids])
  attachments.map(&:purge)
end
```

Feel free to ask for  any doubt

Answer (score 1):

I end up doing things differently but big thanks to @Sandepp Garg who help me getting there.

Because rails don't support a form inside another form I couldn't use the Sandepp's answer. I used my update action to delete the images instead. I don't know if its the best way to do it but it was how I did.

```
#controller
def update
  attachments = ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(id: params[:deleted_img_ids])
  attachments.map(&:purge)

  if @vehicle.update(vehicle_params)
    redirect_to @vehicle
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

```
<!-- view -->
<div class="box_image">
   <div class="box_content">
      <%= image_tag img %>
      <%= check_box_tag "deleted_img_ids[]", img.id %>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I'm doing something really wrong, please let me know. Thanks :)